# Any FTP client which gets Address books(sites) from its internet database

Tags: ftp

I have 3 -4 computers where i have to do work.
I hvae to install ftp on all computers and then manually add all the sites info there.

IN firefox i use xmarks which solves my problem for bokmarks and password.

Now is there any FTP software for windows which stores its sites info , passowrd from internet or atleast synchronises with internet so that i don't have to manually add all the sites on all computers

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this could be accomplished by using the same FTP client across machines and syncing their config file via [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). If they use a config file and not the registry (if it was on Windows), that is.

Comment: Which is the best ftp for that purpose. I use TurboFTP , don't know about config file

Comment: Well, I don't really know that I'm all that qualified to recommend the best FTP client that uses config files (I'm not a pro but I do use FTP sometimes), but I use FileZilla and it keeps its config files in `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\FileZilla` under XP. You could polk around in those kinds of folders on your computer to see if TurboFTP uses config files and where it keeps them if it does.

Comment: +1 FileZilla, if you wanted a copy of JungleDisk will do selective folder syncing for you. I use it to keep my SecureCRT and Filezilla sync'd across all of my computers.

www.jungledisk.com

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is a good one .
usr/pass problem, you can use [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) >. It's really good :)